# Header or meta tag for window size recommendation

Tags: html, http

Is there any HTTP header or HTML meta tag for telling the web client which height and width are the optimal ones for using with a given site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going on a limb here, but are you referring to the viewport meta tag?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=300px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Here is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to the usage of it.

This part is what I find important and relates to your question on that same address.

> The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to
>   a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value
>   device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a
>   scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height
>   values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size
>   or position based on the viewport height.)
>
> The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is
>   first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable
>   properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.